# Which notation to use to express summing probabilities with increasing conditionals?

Tags: notation

How to write this:
$$
\Pr(x_1) + \Pr(x_2|x_1) + \Pr(x_3|x_1,x_2) + \ldots + \Pr(x_n | x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1})
$$
but by using the $\sum$ notation?

I'm trying to write an entropy equation with growing conditionals in $\ldots$:
$$
- \sum_{i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}} \Pr(x_i | \ldots) \ln[\Pr(x_i | \ldots)]
$$
but I don't know how to do express it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?  Not ideal, but seems clear enough:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\rm Pr}(x_i|x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1})$$